# How to get a Hopf algebra from a monoid?

Tags: monoid, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $k$ be a field. Let $S$ be a monoid with netural element $e$.

1. Suppose that all $s \in S$ have only finitely many factoriztions $s=ab$, where $a,b \in S$. Then the free k-module $k[S]$ has a coalgebra structure determined by 
   $$\Delta(s)=\sum \limits_{ab=s}a \otimes b \,\, \text{and} \,\, \varepsilon(s)=\delta_{s, e}$$
2. Define $\Delta(s)= s \otimes s$ and $\varepsilon(s)=1$ for all $s \in S$. Then $k[S]$ is cocommutative bialgebra.

I want to know whether there are other definitions of $\Delta$ on $S$ so that we can get a coalgebra or bialgebra, moreover Hopf algebra structrue? (Maybe for some special semigroups?) Thank you very much.

Comment: Leave it here for 24 hours but then maybe try on mathoverflow.

Comment: You get a Hopf algebra if $S$ is a group, with antipode given by the inverse in $S$.

Comment: there could be many. Suppose $S$ is abelian and finitely generated, then $k[S]$ is a finitely generated commutative. So, you are looking for group (in case Hopf) (or semigroup (in case bialg)) structures on the spectrum. For instance, if $S=N_0^n$ ($n$ copies of the natural numbers including zero), then $k[S]=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. You can define different nilpotent group structures in $k^n$ (take $k=R$, any connected nilpotent Lie group, its universal covering is isomorphic to $R^n$ as manifold) and so, different Hopf algebra structures in $k[S]$.